# Cannot come up with why does my Java code loop infinitely

Tags: java

I tried to do this LeetCode daily challenge but I've found out that my code loops infinitely.

I looked through it multiple times, but I cannot find where the problem is. If anyone could spot it, please answer.

```
public int longestValidParentheses(String s) {
    int count, highestOne = 0, index = 0;
    boolean isSevered = false;
    boolean theEnd = false;
    while(!theEnd) {
        count = 0;
        while(!isSevered) {
            if(index<s.length()-2) {
                if(s.charAt(index) == '(' & s.charAt(index++) == ')') {count = count + 2;index = index+2;}
                else {isSevered = true;}}
            else theEnd=true;isSevered=true;
        }
        highestOne = count;
    }
    return highestOne;
}
```

Comment: `else theEnd=true;isSevered=true;` doesn't do what you think it does. I strongly advise you to use braces on *all* blocks, and use vertical whitespace more liberally, instead of putting multiple statements on a single line. (Get your IDE to reformat your code and you'll see the error...)

Comment: Not the cause of the reported problem, but: your code is only going to count characters that can be an opening parenthesis and a closing parenthesis *at the same time*.  `if(s.charAt(index) == '(' & s.charAt(index++) == ')')`

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions for you:

1. Use indentation and do not write if/else on the same line as the code associated with them
2. Always, ALWAYS use bracelets, even if you have only a single command. I think one of the wrongs java did is letting the programmers the free not to use bracelets if there is just a single command after it. It confusing.

So you have 2 mistakes here that make your code run for infinity:

1. `isSevered` will always be true after one loop exactly, as you change it to true no matter what happens as it is outside the if else statements, hence the reason I wrote the 2 advices above.
2. You never changing `isSeveres` or `theEnd` at the outside loop. Meaning that if `isSevers` is true and `theEnd` is false, you will never enter the internal `while` and will never exit the outside `while`.

The two of those combined means that if the condition that make `theEnd` be initialized with true won't happen at the first run, you will be stuck with infinity loop.